# inverse of gsub

Tags: regex, r

I have some html code I'm working with.  I want to extract certain strings.

I want to extract this from string x preferred using **base R**: `coleman_l, SMOG4`

Here is what I have:

```
x <- "<code>(hi)<a href=\"Read\">auto</a></code>(coleman_l, SMOG4)<br />Read</li>" 
#remove the string (this works)
gsub("a></code>(.+?)<br", "a></code><br", x)

#> gsub("a></code>(.+?)<br", "a></code><br", x)
#[1] "<code>(hi)<a href=\"Read\">auto</a></code><br />Read</li>"

#attempt to extract that information (doesn't work)
re <- "(?<=a></code>().*?(?=)<br)"
regmatches(x, gregexpr(re, x, perl=TRUE))
```

Error message:

```
> regmatches(x, gregexpr(re, x, perl=TRUE)) 
Error in gregexpr(re, x, perl = TRUE) : 
  invalid regular expression '(?<=a></code>().*?(?=)<br)'
In addition: Warning message:
In gregexpr(re, x, perl = TRUE) : PCRE pattern compilation error
        'lookbehind assertion is not fixed length'
        at ')'

    enter code here
```

**NOTE**: *Tagged as regex but this is R specific regex.*

Comment: does the `str_extract` function from `stringr` help?

Comment: @Ben I edited to say preferred base R so this question is more usable by future searchers.  Please add it as a solution.

Comment: I know you said base R, but using the `XML` library and it's friends `htmlTreeParse`  or `xmlTreeParse` might be more appropriate than using regex to deal with html code.

Comment: I'm still not clear. IS something like `gsub(".*a></code>(.+?)<br.*", "\\1", x)` what you're looking for?

Comment: @AnandaMahto perfect.  Please add it as the solution.  That was one attempt I made but I was way off with my `gsub` attempt.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For these types of problems, I would use backreferences to extract the portion I want.

```
x <- 
  "<code>(hi)<a href=\"Read\">auto</a></code>(coleman_l, SMOG4)<br />Read</li>" 
gsub(".*a></code>(.+?)<br.*", "\\1", x)
# [1] "(coleman_l, SMOG4)"
```

If the parentheses should also be removed, add them to the "plain text" part that you are tying to match, but remember that they would need to be escaped:

```
gsub(".*a></code>\\((.+?)\\)<br.*", "\\1", x)
# [1] "coleman_l, SMOG4"
```

Answer (score 7):

FWIW, OP's original approach could have worked with little tweak.

```
> x
[1] "<code>(hi)<a href=\"Read\">auto</a></code>(coleman_l, SMOG4)<br />Read</li>"
> re <- "(?<=a></code>\\().*?(?=\\)<br)"
> regmatches(x, gregexpr(re, x, perl=TRUE))
[[1]]
[1] "coleman_l, SMOG4"
```

An advantage of doing it this way compared to other suggested solution is that if there is possibility of multiple matches, then all of them will show up.

```
> x <- '<code>(hi)<a href=\"Read\">auto</a></code>(coleman_l, SMOG4)<br />Read</li><code>(hi)<a href=\"Read\">auto</a></code>(coleman_l_2, SMOG4_2)<br />Read</li>'
> regmatches(x, gregexpr(re, x, perl=TRUE))
[[1]]
[1] "coleman_l, SMOG4"     "coleman_l_2, SMOG4_2"
```

Comment: Can't you change "re" to `re <- "(?<=a></code>\\().*?(?=\\)<br)"` and ovoid a second `gsub`?

Comment: I swear i tried that but it didn't work :P... amending my solution.

Answer (score 5):

This will work, despite being ugly.

```
x<-"<code>(hi)<a href=\"Read\">auto</a></code>(coleman_l, SMOG4)<br />Read</li>"

x2 <- gsub("^.+(\\(.+\\)).+\\((.+)\\).+$","\\2",x)
x2
[1] "coleman_l, SMOG4"
```

Comment: Are regexes usually pretty? +1

Comment: Haven't seen a useful and pretty regex :-) thanks for your response. +1