# How to select only a subset of corpus terms for TermDocumentMatrix creation in tm

Tags: r, tm, corpus, term-document-matrix

I have a huge corpus, and I'm interested in only appearance of a handful of terms that I know up front. Is there a way to create a term document matrix from the corpus using the `tm` package, where only terms I specify up front are to be used and included?

I know I can subset the resultant TermDocumentMatrix of the corpus, but I want to avoid building the full term document matrix to start with, due to memory size constraint.

Comment: Can you remove the terms you don't want before creating the corpus? Alternatively, can you extract the text from the corpus and remove the undesired terms and then re-generate the corpus?

Comment: I can't remove the terms before creating the corpus, because some of the terms only exist in the post-processed corpus and not in the raw source.

If all else fails, I guess I can extract the text from the post-processed corpus, remove the terms, and rebuild the corpus, as you suggested. But that is going to be very time consuming given my data size, so hopefully there is a direct way that can minimise the steps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can modify a corpus to keep only the terms you want by building a custom transformation function. See the [Vignette for the `tm` package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tm/vignettes/tm.pdf) and the help for the `content_transformer` function for more information:

```
library(tm)

# Create a corpus from the text listed below
corp = VCorpus(VectorSource(doc))

# Custom function to keep only the terms in "pattern" and remove everything else
(f <- content_transformer(function(x, pattern) 
  regmatches(x, gregexpr(pattern, x, perl=TRUE, ignore.case=TRUE))))
```

(FYI, the second line of code just above is adapted from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14765418/inverse-of-gsub/14765750#14765750).)

```
# The pattern we'll search for
keep = "sleep|dream|die"

# Run the transformation function using the pattern above
tm_map(corp, f, keep)[[1]]
```

Here's the result of running the transformation function:

```
<<PlainTextDocument (metadata: 7)>>
  c("die", "sleep", "sleep", "die", "sleep", "sleep", "Dream")
```

Here's the original text I used to create the corpus:

```
doc = "To be, or not to be, that is the question—
Whether 'tis Nobler in the mind to suffer
The Slings and Arrows of outrageous Fortune,
Or to take Arms against a Sea of troubles,
And by opposing, end them? To die, to sleep—
No more; and by a sleep, to say we end
The Heart-ache, and the thousand Natural shocks
That Flesh is heir to? 'Tis a consummation
Devoutly to be wished. To die, to sleep,
To sleep, perchance to Dream; Aye, there's the rub"
```

Answer (score 2):

An another way of filtering a corpus;
First assign your value to the meta part, say *language*; by looping elements of the corpus with the variable *i*, check whatever you want, then filter by using with these meta attribute.

```
corpusz[[i]]$meta["language"] <- 'tur'

idx <- meta(corpusz, "language") ==  'tur'
filtered <- corpusz[idx]
```

Now *filtered* containes only the corpus elements we want.