# Text mining for specific key words in R

Tags: r, corpus, mining

I am using a code piece that produces the histogram/frequency of words in a .txt file converted into corpus, but I want to search for specific key words and plot their frequency...The following code after loading the required packages, loads the text into corpus, does pre-processing/cleaning and generates a histogram of 10 most frequent words

```
  createCorpus <- function(filepath) {
    conn <- file(filepath, "r")
    fulltext <- readLines(conn)
    close(conn)
    vs <- VectorSource(fulltext)
    Corpus(vs, readerControl=list(readPlain, language="en", load=TRUE))
  }

  news_corpus <- createCorpus("sample.txt")
  news_corpus_proc <- tm_map(news_corpus, content_transformer(tolower))
  countWords <- function(filepath, pattern) {
    conn <- file(filepath, "r")
    fulltext <- readLines(conn)
    close(conn)

    count <- 0
    for (i in 1:length(fulltext)) {
      findr <- gregexpr(pattern, fulltext[i])
      if (findr[[1]][1]>0) {
        count <- count + length(findr[[1]])
      }
    }
    count
  }
totwords <- countWords(news_file, " * ") + 10148

mystopwords <- c(" [Aa]nd ", " [Ff]or ", " [Ii]n ", " [Ii]s ", " [Ii]t ",
                 " [Nn]ot ", " [Oo]n ", " [Tt]he ", " [Tt]o ")
totstops <- sum(sapply(mystopwords,
                       function(x) { countWords(news_file, x) }))
totstops/totwords
news_corpus_proc <- tm_map(news_corpus_proc, removeWords,
                           stopwords(kind="en"))
news_corpus_proc <- tm_map(news_corpus_proc, removePunctuation)
news_corpus_proc <- tm_map(news_corpus_proc, removeNumbers)
news_corpus_proc <- tm_map(news_corpus_proc, stripWhitespace)
dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(news_corpus_proc)
dtm.matrix <- as.matrix(dtm)
wordcount <- colSums(dtm.matrix)
topten <- head(sort(wordcount, decreasing=TRUE), 10)
dfplot <- as.data.frame(melt(topten))
dfplot$word <- dimnames(dfplot)[[1]]
dfplot$word <- factor(dfplot$word,
                      levels=dfplot$word[order(dfplot$value,
                                               decreasing=TRUE)])

fig <- ggplot(dfplot, aes(x=word, y=value)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
fig <- fig + xlab("Word in Corpus")
fig <- fig + ylab("Count")
print(fig)
```

Comment: Could you post in more details the expected result?

Comment: Hi Barbara, For example I have a text document about economy, I simply want to look for the frequency of words such as inflation, gdp, unemployment and plot their frequency via histogram

Comment: Take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27008306/how-to-select-only-a-subset-of-corpus-terms-for-termdocumentmatrix-creation-in-t

Comment: Just as a side note, if you are interested in speeding up your code in general, you might have a look at the packages `text2vec` (for creation of dtm and general text mining work flow), `stringi` (to detect and replace patterns), and maybe `tokenizers` (split into tokens, may use Porter stemmer from `SnowballC` and has further cleaning options).

Comment: Thank you Manuel, I think Barbara has caught the point I wanted to make... I will try her suggestion and see